# laravel4でauth::atemptが機能しない

Tags: php, laravel

```
$input = [
    'mail' => Input::get('mail'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
　];

　if (Auth::attempt($input)) {
    echo 'Success';
　} else {
    echo 'Failed';
　}
```

認証できないです
下がUser.phpです。　ほかにどこをみればよいですか

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table ='users';
    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getRememberToken(){
        return $this->remember_token;
    }
    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }
    public function setRememberToken($value){
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }
    public function getRememberTokenName(){
        return 'remember_token';
    }
    public function getReminderEmail()  {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = [
    'email' => Input::get('mail'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
　];
```

上記のコードのように`mail`を`email`に変えて下さい。
データベースのパスワード列は６０文字以上を確認することも必要かも知れません。
登録する時にパスワードをハッシュして下さい。認証の時はハッシュしないように

```
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
```